# How to show failure message on signup using MEAN stack

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

I am developing an SPA which use passport authentication to do the login and signup proccess. The thing is that everything works fine, I can even show a success notification, but I can't find out a way to show an error notification in case the user makes a bad operation.

Here is my code for signup in passport-init:

```
 passport.use('signup', new LocalStrategy({
    passReqToCallback : true
},
function(req, username, password, done){
  var email = req.body.email;
  User.findOne({$or: 
    [
      {username: username},
      {email: email}
    ]
  }, function(err, user){
      if(err){
          return done(err, false);
      }

     if(user) {
          console.log('username or email already taken '+req.body.username);
          return done(null, false, {message: 'Username or email already taken.'});
      }

      user = new User();

      if(req.body.password===req.body.username || req.body.password===req.body.fullname
          || req.body.password===req.body.email){
         console.log('The password can not be equals to your fullname'+
            ', username or email. Try another password.');
          return done(null, false, {message: 'The password can not be equals to your fullname'+
            ', username or email. Try another password.'});
      }
```

Then if non of this cases happens the method returns no errors with the user data.

Here is the route code to pass results to angular:

```
  router.get('/failure', function(req, res){
    res.send({state: 'failure', user: null, message: "Invalid username or password"});
});

router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('signup',{
    successRedirect: '/auth/success',
    failureRedirect: '/auth/failure',
    failureFlash: true
}));
```

And finally I got this angular in order to call and get a response:

```
$scope.register = function(){
    $http.post('/auth/signup', $scope.user).then(

    function(data){
        $rootScope.authenticated = true;
        $rootScope.current_user = data.user.username;
        $rootScope.signUp = true;
    },

      function(data, status){
        console.log(status);
      }
    );
};
```

This is it. Ofcourse the angular code is inside a controller. I just began learning to build MEAN stack applications so, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's a custom error/ custom logic you should send an error back to the client:

```
if(user)
return done({error:'userAlreadyTaken'},false);
```

the same for the other conditions you have in your code.

Comment: But... how do I get that error message back in Angular? I mean in case is passport failure how to get that in the `register()` function... Thanks for answering

Comment: check what you get in data after the promise is fulfilled, you can do a rudimentary case statement depending on the error you get in the data, do an alert(JSON.stringify(data)) or a console log

Comment: I did what you said, I wrote that in the done function instead of the old code. But I got this: `POST /auth/signup 500 348.252 ms - 32`.

Comment: ok what do you get in the response? the error you sent from the server?, if that's the case you probably could use an interceptor to catch the error in agularjs

Comment: Many thanks man!! I finally did it. The key was to make what you said, to make a call of the JSON data. I let the error logic like the original one and it works perfect! Thanks again!.